# can kustomize merge PatchesJson6902 from bases and overlays?

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I have been working with one [`patchesJson6902`](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/builtins/#_patchesjson6902_) clause in my Kubernetes kustomize configuration; now I want to use overlays (to support different instances) and I want to split the patches (some patches are generic, i.e. for enabling let's-encrypt instead of self-signed for cert-manager for some instances; other patches are specific, i.e. for distinct certificate hostname per instance).

I have a `base/04-public-letsencrypt-ingress/kustomization.yaml`

```yaml
…
patchesJson6902:
- target: { group: networking.k8s.io, version: v1, kind: Ingress, name: ingress-frontend }
  path: ingress-letsencrypt.patch.yaml
```

and a `overlay/04-public-letsencrypt-ingress/kustomization.yaml`

```yaml
bases:
- ../../base/04-public-letsencrypt-ingress/

patchesJson6902:
- target: { group: networking.k8s.io, version: v1, kind: Ingress, name: ingress-frontend }
  path: ingress-tls-hostname.patch.yaml
```

This does not work as I expected, it seems only one of the `patchesJson6902` definitions becomes effective.

Is this the expected behavior? Is there a good way to split patches; maybe is there an alternative to `patchesJson6902` that can also works when defined in multiple places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: the `patchesJson6902` directive has been deprecated; you should simply be using `patches`.

With respect to your question, when you include a base kustomization in the `resources` section of your `kustomization.yaml`, kustomize neither knows or cares that the base used patches: the patches in your local `kustomization.yaml` are simply applied to whatever manifests are generated by your `resources` section (and config/secret generators, etc).

So for example if we have this layout:

```
.
├── base
│   ├── ingress.yaml
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   └── set-ingressclass-patch.yaml
└── overlay
    ├── kustomization.yaml
    └── set-ingress-tls-patch.yaml
```

And the following files:

- `base/ingress.yaml`:

  ```
  apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    name: example
  spec:
    rules:
    - host: www.example.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: example
              port:
                name: http
  ```
- `base/set-ingressclass-patch.yaml`:

  ```
  - path: /metadata/annotations
    op: add
    value:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  ```
- `base/kustomization.yaml`:

  ```
  apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
  kind: Kustomization
  commonLabels:
    app: example

  resources:
  - ingress.yaml

  patches:
    - target:
        kind: Ingress
        name: example
      path: set-ingressclass-patch.yaml
  ```
- `overlay/set-ingress-tls-patch.yaml`:

  ```
  - path: /metadata/annotations/cert-manager.io~1cluster-issuer
    op: add
    value: my_issuer
  - path: /spec/tls
    op: add
    value:
      - hosts:
        - www.example.com
        secretName: example-cert
  ```
- `overlay/kustomization.yaml`:

  ```
  apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
  kind: Kustomization

  resources:
    - ../base

  patches:
    - target:
        kind: Ingress
        name: example
      path: set-ingress-tls-patch.yaml
  ```

Then running `kustomize build base` produces:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  labels:
    app: example
  name: example
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: example
            port:
              name: http
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
```

And running `kustomize build overlay` produces:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: my_issuer
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  labels:
    app: example
  name: example
spec:
  rules:
  - host: www.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: example
            port:
              name: http
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - www.example.com
    secretName: example-cert
```

Here we can see that the output of the second `kustomize build` commands takes the manifests produced by `base` -- which include the patch that sets the ingress class -- and applies the patches in `overlay/set-ingress-tls-patch.yaml`.

---

You didn't show examples of your patches, so it's hard to tell what's actually going on, but I have a theory. Let's take a closer look at the patches in this example.

The manifest `base/ingress.yaml` doesn't have an `metadata.annotations` section. Our patch...

```
- path: /metadata/annotations
  op: add
  value:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
```

...creates the `annotations` key and content. But when we apply patches in the overlay, the Ingress resource already has an `annotations` section. If we had written `overlay/set-ingress-tls-patch.yaml` like this:

```
- path: /metadata/annotations
  op: add
  value:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: my_issuer
```

That would have *replaced* the `annotations` key with a new value! The resulting manifest would look like:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: my_issuer
  labels:
    app: example
  name: example
spec:
  ...
```

But we don't want to *replace* the `annotations` section; we want to add a new key. So instead our patch looks like:

```
- path: /metadata/annotations/cert-manager.io~1cluster-issuer
  op: add
  value: my_issuer
```

This is adding a new key under `annotations`, rather than replacing the entire `annotations` key. The pattern `~1` is how you [escape a forward slash in a JSON pointer expression](https://github.com/json-patch/json-patch-tests/issues/42).

---

The above all works, but I using strategic merge patches would be simpler and more obvious. In that case, `base/set-ingressclass-patch.yaml` would look like:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  name: example
```

And `base/set-ingress-tls-patch.yaml` would look like:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: my_issuer
  name: example
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - www.example.com
    secretName: example-cert
```

Using this style of patch, you don't need to set a `target` in your `kustomization.yaml` because the target is implied by the `kind` and `metadata.name` in the patch. E.g., `base/kustomization.yaml` would look like:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
commonLabels:
  app: example

resources:
- ingress.yaml

patches:
  - path: set-ingressclass-patch.yaml
```

I think that's easier to understand than the JSONPatch style patches, but that's a matter of opinion and as we've demonstrated here either will work.